# Understanding how spring-data handles @EntityGraph

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

(I made a [SSCCE](https://github.com/ArnaudDenoyelle/sscce-entity-graph) for this question.)

I have 2 simple entities : `Employee` and `Company`. `Employee` has a `@ManyToOne` relationship with `Company` with default fetch strategy (eager).

I want to be able to load the `Employee` without the `Company`without changing the fetch strategy defined in the `Employee` because I need to do that for only one use case.

JPA's entity graph seems to be intended for this purpose.

So I defined a `@NamedEntityGraph`on the class `Employee`:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "employeeOnly")
public class Employee {

  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  @ManyToOne
  private Company company;

  //Getters & Setters
```

And a `EmployeeRepository` like this :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {

  @EntityGraph(value = "employeeOnly", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
  List<Employee> findByCompanyId(Integer companyId);

}
```

Despite the use of `@EntityGraph`, I can see in the logs that the `Company` is still loaded by hibernate :

```
2016-11-07 23:16:08.738 DEBUG 1029 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select employee0_.id as id1_1_, employee0_.company_id as company_4_1_, employee0_.name as name2_1_, employee0_.surname as surname3_1_ from employee employee0_ left outer join company company1_ on employee0_.company_id=company1_.id where company1_.id=?
2016-11-07 23:16:08.744 DEBUG 1029 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select company0_.id as id1_0_0_, company0_.name as name2_0_0_ from company company0_ where company0_.id=?
```

Why? How to avoid that?

Comment: If you define company LAZY is company loaded or not?

Comment: @simas_ch If I define the company LAZY, the employee and its company are loaded in the same request, using an outer join.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hibernate did not support handling non-lazy attributes as lazy, even with entity graphs. There was an issue for this: [HHH-8776](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8776), but it's fixed now.

Previously, the only solution for the time being was to make the association lazy.

Comment: If you took the source code based on his case study, you could see that even give `FetchType.LAZY` not solved the problem.

Comment: @xsalefter I took the provided source code, and making the association lazy solved the problem - the additional query to load the company was not executed.

Comment: Hm. Your result probably different. But I double checked in my machine just to make sure, before make this statement:

The result is the "almost" same: Altough `FetchType.LAZY` produce only 1 query, the result is something like this:

`select employee0_.id as id1_1_, employee0_.company_id as company_4_1_, employee0_.name as name2_1_, employee0_.surname as surname3_1_ from employee employee0_ left outer join company company1_ on employee0_.company_id=company1_.id where company1_.id=?`

It is product left outer join, which is, in my opinion, not "a perfect solution".

Comment: This is why I propose to use `@Query` in my answer, which is, I think, solve the OP problem.

Comment: @xsalefter That's true when it comes to the outer join, but that is not what the OP asks about. The OP wants to get rid of the additional query for loading the company. And even with your solution, the additional query gets executed if the association is eager.

Comment: no it is not. Check this [Employee](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/denodev/model/Employee.java) . No `FetchType.LAZY` at all. My guess is that, when spring found there's string query in `@Query` annotation, they not generate JPQL by them self and delegate back JPQL query producer to hibernate, and back to nature of hibernate that _all association are lazy by default_ . Anyway, this is could be an improvement or bug in spring-data-jpa itself.

Comment: @xsalefter You are sure you executed the query which actually returned some data? E.g. searching employees for a company with id `42`?

Comment: Yes. Check this [test](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/blob/master/src/test/java/com/denodev/service/CustomServiceTest.java). Well, sorry for rough test name, etc, but just look at to the query.

Comment: @xsalefter I tried specifying the query explicitly, the outcome is as expected, additional query is fired: `select company0_.id as id1_0_0_, company0_.name as name2_0_0_ from company company0_ where company0_.id=?`. You are sure that initialization is done correctly in your test, i.e. data with company `42` is inserted before running the test, etc? If you don't observe the additional query, it means that your query does not return any employees.

Comment: @Dragon. You are right. `@Query` won't work without specify `FetchType.LAZY` explicitly in entity class. I update my answer as well as example in my github repository. Thanks.

Comment: Seems a bug in Hibernate

Answer (score 5):

### Modified Answer

per-[specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html), the fetch type for `@ManyToOne` is `EAGER` by default. But even through we set:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Company company;
```

You will get the same result. The problem because the way spring-data-jpa create HQL/JPQL for you. So adding `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` <del>won't work</del> is not enough. To solve this, use`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` **and** `@Query` annotation in your repository:

**Employee.java** :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Company company;
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
@Query("from Employee e where e.company.id = :companyId")
List<Employee> findByCompanyIdUsingQuery(@Param("companyId") Integer companyId);
```

In the test, this is SQL that generated by your `loadByCompanyId()` (which is generate left outer join):

```
select employee0_.id as id1_1_, employee0_.company_id as company_4_1_, employee0_.name as name2_1_, employee0_.surname as surname3_1_ from employee employee0_ left outer join company company1_ on employee0_.company_id=company1_.id where company1_.id=?
```

And this is SQL generated by method that use `@Query` annotation:

```
select employee0_.id as id1_1_, employee0_.company_id as company_4_1_, employee0_.name as name2_1_, employee0_.surname as surname3_1_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.company_id=?
```

You could check the latest code in [my repository](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate).

HTH.

Comment: Downvote? Without any single explanation? What is that? If it was about the wrong URL for @ManyToOne, I fixed that.

Comment: If I add `(fetchType = LAZY)`, the relationship is loaded with a join instead of being loaded in a separate request. If I use your `@Query`, I still have 2 requests. I I use `(fetchType = LAZY)` AND your `@Query`, it works. It does not solve the problem but deserves an upvote :) (I did not downvote and don't know who did and why).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I modified my answer and github repository example as well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bug in Hibernate.

@Dragan Bozanovic you are right. I only see one workaround in this case.

Set fetch = lazy

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Employee.withCompany" , attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("company"))
public class Employee {

  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Company company;
```

Introduce new method for loading company eagerly

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {


  List<Employee> findByCompanyId(Integer companyId);

  @Query("select e from Employee e left join e.company c where c.id = :companyId")
  @EntityGraph(value = "Employee.withCompany", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
  List<Employee> findByCompanyIdFetchingCompany(@Param("companyId") Integer companyId);

}
```

And use following two interchangeably where required

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/by-company/{id}")
  public void loadByCompanyId(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    employeeService.loadByCompanyId(id);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/by-company/eager-company/{id}")
  public void loadByCompanyIdFetchingCompany(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    employeeService.loadByCompanyIdFetchingCompany(id);
  }
```

First one (for lazy loading) http://localhost:8080/employees/by-company/42

```
select employee0_.id as id1_1_, employee0_.company_id as company_4_1_, employee0_.name as name2_1_, employee0_.surname as surname3_1_ from employee employee0_ left outer join company company1_ on employee0_.company_id=company1_.id where company1_.id=?
```

Second (eager loading) http://localhost:8080/employees/by-company/eager-company/42

```
select employee0_.id as id1_1_0_, company1_.id as id1_0_1_, employee0_.company_id as company_4_1_0_, employee0_.name as name2_1_0_, employee0_.surname as surname3_1_0_, company1_.name as name2_0_1_ from employee employee0_ left outer join company company1_ on employee0_.company_id=company1_.id where company1_.id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

I was under impression you have to specify fields within your Graph definition.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm (43.1.2.1 Fetch Graphs)

> A fetch graph consists of only the fields explicitly specified in the
>   EntityGraph instance, and ignores the default entity graph settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not so cool solution is using a native query.

```
 @Query(value = "select * from employee where company_id= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Employee> findByCompanyId(Integer companyId);
```

I tested it and it was giving expected results, without being forced to set  fetch = FetchType.LAZY

Answer (score 0):

though the association is lazy by specifying (fetch=FetchType.Lazy) the company is exposed with a separate query call because you are exposing the **Entity** Employee which has property company. If you don't want the company to be exposed then either use @JsonIgnore, which is not very much recommended. And here comes one of the reasons why we make used of DTO so that we can expose only the required fields. You can create an EmployeeDTO with employee specific fields keep the association lazy which will ensure that separate query is not executed to fetch company details and map the entity to DTO either explicitly or you can make use of MapSturct Api